# Django template question

Tags: python, django, django-templates

How can I achieve this using the Django template system:

Say I have 2 variable passed to the template system:

```
days=[1,2,3,4,5]
items=[ {name:"apple,day:3},{name:"orange,day:5} ]
```

I want to have such output as a table:

```
        1   2    3    4    5
apple   n   n    y    n    n
orange  n   n    n    n    y
```

As you can notice, giving "n" to non matching ones and "y" to matching.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what Ignacio meant. That said, I probably agree with Daniel that you should do this in the view.

```
<table>
{% for item in items %}
  <tr>
    <td>{% item.name %}</td>
    {% for dday in days %}
    <td>
      {% ifequal dday item.day %}y{% else %}n{% endifequal %}
    </td>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

I've called the days loop variable 'dday' to make it clear that the lookup `item.day` here is actually getting `item['day']`.

Answer (score 6):

Why don't you define this logic in the django view, and then simply pass arrays of Ys and Ns to the template?

Comment: simplest&best solution if your views->templates are a one-to-one match

Comment: Do the least you can do in the templates.

Answer (score 2):

Two loops. The outer loop is through `items`, the inner through `days`. Test if `outer[day]` is equal to `inner`, and output `y` if so and `n` if not.

Comment: cant do this with django 1.1 :(

Comment: That makes no sense. It's two for tags and a ifequal tag.